# How can I p4 copy a file from the depot to my pwd?

Tags: perforce

I want to diff two different versions of the same file in a P4 depot using tkdiff.  But P4 diff2 doesn't support P4DIFF so I'm trying to simply copy the two files to my PWD and then diff them right from there.  But I'm having a problem with using p4 copy to get the file (if that' even the right way to do this).  I tried

```
"p4 copy -s //this/that/theother/here/there/where/the.file#77 ./v77"
```

but it complains with

```
"Missing/wrong number of arguments."
```

The documentation says...

```
p4 [g-opts] copy [-c change] [-n -f -v -q] [-m max] -b branch -s fromFile[rev] [toFile …]
```

"p4 files //this/that/theother/here/there/where/the.file#77" recognizes the file.  It's real, it's there.  But I just can't copy it.

Maybe I should just ask the question... Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  If so, how?

p4 info gives...
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)
Ya, I know, ancient.  Beyond my control.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 4):

`p4 copy` is for copying files within the depot.  You want `p4 print`:

```
p4 print -o ./v77 //this/that/theother/here/there/where/the.file#77
```

Without any flags, `p4 print` will just print the file contents to stdout.  The `-o` flag tells it to write the output into the specified local file.  Unlike the local files created by `p4 sync`, the output file isn't tracked in any way, so you're responsible for cleaning it up when you're done.

If you want to diff two versions of the same file without having to create and clean up your own temp files, `p4 diff -f` is also an option:

```
p4 set P4DIFF=tkdiff
p4 sync the.file#78
p4 diff -f the.file#77
```

Comment: Perfect !   Thank You Samwise !